# Django Celery Task: AttributeError: type object 'Command' has no attribute '__annotations__'

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to set up a celery task which basically runs a script to deactivate a bunch of facilities inside a json file. I used to run it manually and it ran fine but now i get the following error when Celery tries to run it as a task:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Command' has no attribute '__annotations__'
```

Can anyone tell me why it is not working?
This is the code i am using:

tasks.py

```
import requests
import json

from project.users.models import Facility
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from config import celery_app

IMPORT_URL = 'https://example.com/file.json'

@celery_app.task()
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def delete_facility(self, data):
                    
                    data = data
                    

                    if Facility.objects.filter(UUID=data, ReportedStatusField='closed'):
                        
                        print("Facility status already set to closed")


                    else:
                        
                        facility, facility_closed = Facility.objects.update_or_create(UUID=data,
                            defaults={
                            'ReportedStatusField': 'closed'
                            }
                        )
                        print("Facility status set to closed")
                        

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        response = requests.get(
            url=IMPORT_URL,
            headers=headers,
        )

        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()


        for data, data_object in data.items():
            if data in ["deleted"]:
                for data in data_object:
                    self.delete_facility(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figured it out. It's properly running now. I'm calling the base command file from the tasks.py instead of adding the code directly into the tasks.py:

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.management import call_command

@shared_task
def start_import():
    call_command("import_from_url", )
```